# Scala value toInt is not a member of Option[String]

Tags: scala

I am new with Scala and I can't figure this out. I am sure it is a simple solution but as a newbie I can't find it.

I have this code

```
val resID = CartManager.getReservation(request)
   val id = if (resID.isDefined && resID.get.status == "FOUND") resID.get.id.toInt else -1
```

and it gives me an error:

```
value toInt is not a member of Option[String]
```

How can I get the id of the object Reservation if it is defined?

Thank you

Comment: `resID.get.id.get.toInt` should work fine. However, you should first check that the `id` itself is defined first. But most important, you should really avoid doing those kinds of check and use either pattern matching or `Option`'s methods such as `Option.map`/`Option.flatMap`/`Option.getOrElse`/`Option.orElse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better functional way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be like this:

```
val id = CartManager.getReservation(request).filter(_.status == "FOUND").map(_.id.toInt).getOrElse(-1)
```

Use `filter` to filter down the contained `Option` value (if it exists), `map` to map the `CartManager` to an `Option[Int]`, and `getOrElse` to extract the value from the `Option` with the default value `-1` if the `Option` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

That means your `id` is Option[String], and not String. 
Also, you can use a for-comprehension here.

```
   val id = ( for {
       resID <- CartManager.getReservation(request) if resID.status == "FOUND"
       theID <- resID.id 
      } yield theID.toInt ) getOrElse -1
```